# Dot function in unreal c++

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

This is the code in Unreal C++

```
float GetT( float t, float alpha, const FVector& p0, const FVector& p1 )
{
    auto d  = p1 - p0;
    float a = d | d; // Dot product
    float b = FMath::Pow( a, alpha*.5f );
    return (b + t);
}
```

Does this line means  "float a = d | d; // Dot product"   dot product of FVector d with itself

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_Catmull%E2%80%93Rom_spline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look for documentation of `FVector`. Search "operators". Look for `|`. [Find](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/API/Runtime/Core/Math/FVector/):

> ```
> float     
>
> operator|
>
> (
>     const FVector& V
> )
> ```
>
> Calculate the dot product between this and another vector.

Yes. `d | d` calculates the dot product of the vector with itself.